# PHP & MySQL: How to select rows in 10 minute increments

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a MySQL SELECT that will only pull in rows in 10 minute increments (or sufficiently close to 10 min increments). My data is recorded about once a minute per row, but the timing of the INSERT isn't always exact. Each row has a datetime column.

My first idea was to pull in a whole bunch of rows then weed them out with a PHP function. That approach is messy and I'd much rather do this with a smarter MySQL query. Is it possible?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pairs ORDER BY pair_id DESC LIMIT 2000;");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['SomeTimestamp'] . " " . $row['SomeValue'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You can write a cron job to run your php script every 10 minutes.

Comment: I'm trying to pull a list of values from existing data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fetch all the records with timestamp within last 10min.

```
SELECT * FROM pairs WHERE SomeTimestamp > DATE_SUB(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use WHERE and date function
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE /* select the lines that in the range of 10 mins */